# Approximating an infinite sum of only odd terms by a definite integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Consider the infinite Sum

$S=\sum\limits_{n\ \text{odd}}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{nt}\right)^2\left[1-i\left(nt\right)^2\right]^{-1}$

Is there a way to approximate this sum as a contour integral? In my physical problem it is valid to make the approximation $t\to 0$ in a certain regime (or more precisely, the approximation that $t$ is very small). So I tried the following:

Let us set aside the fact (for now) that this is a sum over odd terms only. So we rewrite the sum as

$S=\dfrac{1}{t}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{nt}\right)^2\left[1-i\left(nt\right)^2\right]^{-1}$

$\ \ =\dfrac{1}{t}\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{nt}\right)^2\left[1-i\left(nt\right)^2\right]^{-1}$

$\ \ =\dfrac{1}{t}\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-ix^2}\ dx$

(i.e.) setting $t\to dx$ and $nt\to x$ as this resembles a Riemann sum. But this doesn't work because the integral does not converge. Is there a nice way to approximate this infinite sum? Ideally, it'll be great if there is a way to do this without assuming $t$ is small.

**EDIT:** Corrected the problem statement based on Blumenthal's comment.

Comment: There's something funny with the units, so to speak. Even before dealing with the problem of a sum over odd $n$, what you'd have in the limit $t \rightarrow 0$ is that $t \rightarrow dx$ and $n \cdot t \rightarrow x$, not $n/t \rightarrow x$. Do you understand why?

Comment: I have non-dimensionalized all the variables in the problem. So $t$ here is dimensionless. It is not time. Sorry if this was confusing! I think the sum as stated in the first equation looks fine?

Comment: I'm speaking loosely when I say 'units'. My point was that if $t$ is supposed to become infinitesimal, then you should expect $n \cdot t \rightarrow x$, not the other way. The problem here is that to even begin a Riemann Sum argument for a summand over a set (here, it's $\mathbb{N}$), for instance, you need that $\{t n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ serves as a 'fine enough' mesh for the positive reals in the limit at $t \rightarrow 0$. The set $\{n / t \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ flies off to infinity as $t \rightarrow 0$, and will be useless as a mesh.

Comment: Are you summing over positive $n$ only?

Comment: @ABlumenthal Yes, you are correct! I see your point --- I have corrected the problem statement now. Indeed,looking at the physics of my problem, the actual useful limit is $t\to 0$ as defined in the corrected statement.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, I'm summing only over positive $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applies to the question in its form on **Wed May 14 2014**. It seems  to have escaped attention  that this sum  may be evaluated
using  harmonic  summation   techniques.  This  will  provide  another
integral representation by a complex line integral.

To see this, introduce the sum
$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1}
\left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)x}\right)^2
\frac{1}{1-i((2k-1)x)^2}$$
with $x$ a real number.

This sum converges absolutely and  it is harmonic and may be evaluated
by inverting its Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = 2k-1 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{1-ix^2}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{1-ix^2}
\times x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1-ix^2}
\times x^{s-3} dx.$$

Compute the fundamental strip of  this transform. In a neighborhood of
zero, $g(x)  \sim 1/x^2$ and  we need $(s-1)-2  > -1$ so  the integral
converges when $\Re(s)>2$.  At  infinity $g(x) \sim 1/x^4$ which gives
convergence  for   $(s-1)-4<-1$  or   $\Re(s)  <  4.$   Therefore  the
fundamental strip is $\langle 2, 4 \rangle.$

We evaluate $g^*(s)$ by using a semicircular contour in the upper half
plane    with    radius    $R$    going    to    infinity    traversed
counterclockwise. Along  the positive real  axis we get  the transform
$g^*(s).$  Along  the negative  real  axis  we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^0   \frac{1}{1-ix^2}   \times    x^{s-3}   dx   
= - \int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{1-iu^2}  \times e^{i\pi  (s-3)} u^{s-3} du 
\\ = e^{i\pi (s-1)} g^*(s) = - e^{i\pi s} g^*(s).$$

The sole pole in the upper half plane is at $x=e^{3/4\pi i}$ and since
the pole is simple we have
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1-ix^2} x^{s-3}; x=e^{3/4\pi i} \right)
= \frac{1}{-2i\times e^{3/4\pi i}} e^{3/4\pi i(s-3)}
\\ = \frac{i}{2} e^{3/4\pi i(s-4)}
= -\frac{i}{2} e^{3/4\pi i s}.$$
This yields for $g^*(s)$ that
$$g^*(s) (1 - e^{i\pi s})
= 2\pi i \times -\frac{i}{2} e^{3/4\pi i s}$$ so that
$$g^*(s) = \pi \frac{ e^{3/4\pi i s} }{1 - e^{i\pi s}}
= \pi e^{1/4\pi i s} \frac{1}{e^{-1/2 i\pi s} - e^{1/2 i\pi s}}
\\= - \frac{\pi}{2i} \frac{e^{1/4\pi i s}}{\sin(1/2 \pi s)}
= \frac{\pi i}{2} \frac{e^{1/4\pi i s}}{\sin(1/2 \pi s)}.$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{\pi i}{2} \frac{e^{1/4\pi i s}}{\sin(1/2 \pi s)}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)
\\ \text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1}  \frac{1}{(2k-1)^s}
= \left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

The   Mellin   inversion   integral   here   is   $$\frac{1}{2\pi   i}
\int_{5/2-i\infty}^{5/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$  which we evaluate by
shifting it to  the right for an expansion  about infinity. The choice
of line was  determined by the fundamental strip  of $g^*(s)$ which is
completely embedded in the half-plane of convergence $\Re(s)>1$ of the
sum term.

We  now proceed  to  collect  the contribution  in  residues from  the
poles. These  originate in  the sine term  only at values  $s=2q$ with
$q\ge 2,$ giving
$$\frac{\pi i}{2}
\sum_{q\ge 2} e^{1/2\pi i q} \times
(-1)^q \frac{2}{\pi} \times
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2q}}\right) \zeta(2q)
\times \frac{1}{x^{2q}}
\\ = 
i \sum_{q\ge 2} e^{3/2\pi i q} \times
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2q}}\right) \zeta(2q)
\times \frac{1}{x^{2q}}.$$
To simplify this we need to evaluate the sum
$$T(u) = \sum_{q\ge 2} u^{2q} \zeta(2q)
= \sum_{q\ge 2} u^{2q} 
\frac{(-1)^{q+1} B_{2q} (2\pi)^{2q}}{2(2q)!}
= - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q\ge 2} B_{2q}
\frac{(2\pi i u)^{2q}}{(2q)!}.$$

Using the generating function of the Bernoulli numbers we have that
$$\sum_{p\ge 4} B_p \frac{t^p}{p!}
= -1 + \frac{1}{2} t - \frac{1}{12} t + \frac{t}{e^t-1}$$
which gives for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}(2\pi i u) 
+ \frac{1}{24} (2\pi i u)^2
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{2\pi i u}{e^{2\pi i u} - 1}.$$
The expansion that we have is given by 
$$i T(e^{3/4 \pi i}/x) - i T(e^{3/4 \pi i}/x/2)$$

The closed  form for the  sum is actually  the negative of  this value
because we are integrating counterclockwise.
Doing the substitution we finally obtain
$${\frac {1/8\,\sqrt {2}\pi -1/8\,i\pi \,\sqrt {2}}{x}}
+1/8\,{\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{{x}
^{2}}}
- \frac{\pi e^{3/4 \pi i}/x}{e^{2\pi i e^{3/4 \pi i}/x}-1}
+ \frac{\pi e^{3/4 \pi i}/x/2}{e^{2\pi i e^{3/4 \pi i}/x/2}-1}.$$
This expansion holds everywhere the original series converges, i.e.
$(-\infty, 0)\cup (0, \infty).$

Answer (score 2):

(This is an answer to a previous version of the question.)

You can express your sum as a power series in $t$.  First rewrite your sum as

$$
S = i \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^4}{1+i\left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^2}.
$$

For $|t| < 1$ and $n\geq 0$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{1+i\left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^2} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-i)^m \left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^{2m},
$$

so that, by changing the order of summation,

$$
\begin{align}
S &= i \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^4 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-i)^m \left(\frac{t}{2n+1}\right)^{2m+4} \\
&= i \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-i)^m t^{2m+4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2m+4}} \\
&= i \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-i)^m (1-4^{-m-2}) \zeta(2m+4) t^{2m+4},
\end{align}
$$

where we have used the identity

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^\alpha} = (1-2^{-\alpha})\zeta(\alpha).
$$

It follows, for example, that

$$
S = i \frac{\pi^4}{96} t^4 + \frac{\pi^6}{960} t^6 + O(t^8)
$$

as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this might work for me. I just corrected the problem statement based on what @ABlumenthal pointed out. I guess, your solution still works be replacing $t$ with $1/t$

Comment: It'll be a great help if you can modify your solution based on the corrected problem statement.

Comment: @G.H.Hardly, I don't see an easy way to adapt my method to the current problem statement.  It might be better to un-accept my answer in the hopes that someone else can answer your revised question.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Your method might still work, but the complication is that your series expansion for the geometric sum is no longer valid for huge $n$. I'm guessing the procedure here would be to fix $t$ small and find some estimate for the tail of the sum (here 'tail' means $n > 1/t$).

Comment: @AntonioVargas On second thought, the tail $\{n > 1/t\}$ will resemble some kind of Riemann sum of an integrable function (since the bounds of integration are now $1$ to $\infty$) with a factor of $1/t$ outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following closed form for the sum

$$  -\frac{\sqrt{2}\left( 1+\,i \right) \pi}{32\,t^2} \, \left( (i-1)\pi \,\sqrt {2}+4\,t\,\tan
 \left( {\frac { \left( 1-i \right) \pi \,\sqrt {2}}{4\,t}}
 \right)  \right). $$

**Check** Here is the original answer by Maple in case I made a mistake while trying to improve the format in the above answer

$$ \left( -1/32-1/32\,i \right) \pi \, \left( i\pi \,\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan
 \left( {\frac { \left( 1/4-1/4\,i \right) \pi \,\sqrt {2}}{t}}
 \right) t-\pi \,\sqrt {2} \right) \sqrt {2}{t}^{-2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I got the same answer with Mathematica too. I'm really looking for an analytical way to find the sum. Even a good approximation for $S$, or an approximation valid under certain restrictions on $t$ would work just fine.

Comment: @G.H.Hardly: It is a nice closed form in terms of elementary functions!